# What is the rationale behind AJAX cross-domain security?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Given the simplicity of writing a server side proxy that fetches data across domains, I'm at a loss as to what the initial intention was in preventing client side AJAX from making calls across domains.  I'm not asking for speculation, I'm looking for documentation from the language designers (or people close to them) for what they thought they were doing, other than simply creating a mild inconvenience for developers.

TIA

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709423(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy_for_XMLHttpRequest Whole book worth reading.

Comment: @jasssonpet Awesome link, bookmarked it!

Comment: @jasssonpet, You should post that link as an answer, I'd give it the checkmark. I don't agree with their concerns, but I can see that this was their rationale, which was precisely my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It's to prevent that a browser acts as a reverse proxy**. Suppose  you are browsing http://www.evil.com from a PC at your office, and suppose that in that office exists an intranet with sensitive information at http://intranet.company.com which is only accessible from the local network. 
**If the cross domain policy wouldn't exists, www.evil.com could made ajax requests to http://intranet.company.com, using your browser as a reverse proxy**, and send that information to www.evil.com with another Ajax request.

This one of the reasons of the restriction I guess.

Comment: Yes it is :)... very more clear than my answer, I lost one's way

Comment: that seems *extremely far fetched. Your intranet would have to have AJAX responders which evil.com would have to know how to call! If that's really the concern, then the intranet can't be running any CGI either, right?

Comment: As @GrabrielJürgens said, without _cross domain policy_ any URI in your intranet (not only CGI, I don't know what AJAX responder is) is compromised. The attacker can know the specific URI to call or just make force brute attempts, doesn't matter, it is a real security problem.

Comment: Hi @Dr.Dredel! I'm not sure if I understand what yo wrote about CGI, but with Ajax, you can access almost any document hosted by a http server, not necessarily CGI, and in my opinion is not a good practice to relay the security of a browser in the assumption that the possibly attacker doesn't know a supposedly private URL. Personally, I wouldn't use any browser that allows a hacker to do that on my local network.

Answer (score 2):

The most important reason for this limit is a security concern: should JSON request make browser serve and accept cookies or security credentials with request to another domain? It is not a concern with server-side proxy, because it don't have direct access to client environment. There was [a proposal for safe sanitized JSON-specific request methods](http://www.json.org/JSONRequest.html), but it wasn't implemented anywhere yet.

Answer (score 2):

If you're the author for myblog.com and you make an XHR to facebook.com, should the request send your facebook cookie credentials? No, that would mean that you could request users' private facebook information from your blog.

If you create a proxy service to do it, your proxy can't access the facebook cookies.

You may also be questioning why JSONP is OK. The reason is that you're loading a script you didn't write, so unless facebook's script decides to send you the information from their JS code, you won't have access to it

Comment: Maybe I'm not as familiar with XHR as I should be... Is there an inherent ability on the part of XHR to pull and examine cookies? I thought cookies were a separate mechanism, and XHR was specifically (and exclusively) a data transfer mechanism for HTTP requests.

Comment: XHR is an HTTP request. It always sends cookies for the domain you're connecting to, just like when you request an HTML page or an image from that domain, look at your headers going out if you make an XHR to your own page, or request an image, script, or even an iframe from another server

Answer (score 1):

The difference between direct access and a proxy are cookies and other security relevant identification/verification information which are absolutely restricted to one origin.

With those, your browser can access sensitive data. Your proxy won't, as it does not know the user's login data.

Therefore, the proxy is only applicable to public data; as is [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Answer (score 1):

I know you are asking for experts' answers, I'm just a neophyte, and this is my opinion to why the *server side proxy* is not a proper final solution:

- Building a *server side proxy* is not as easy as not build it at all.
- Not always is possible like in a *Third Party JS widget*. You are not gonna ask all your publisher to declare a DNS register for integrate your widget. And modify the `document.domain` of his pages with the colateral issues.
- As I read in the book [Third Party Javascript](http://thirdpartyjs.com/) *"it requires loading an intermediary tunnel file before it can make cross-domain requests"*. At least you put JSONP in the game with more tricky juggling.
- Not supported by IE8, also from the above book: *"IE8 has a rather odd bug that prevents a top-level domain from communicating with its subdomain even when they both opt into a common domain namespace"*.
- There are several security matters as people have explained in other answers, even more than them, you can check the chapter *4.3.2 Message exchange using subdomain proxies* of the above book.

And the most important for me:

- It is a hack.. like the JSONP solution, it's time for an standard, reliable, secure, clean and confortable solution.

But, after re-read your question, I think I still didn't answer it, so **Why this AJAX security?**, again I think, the answer is:

**Because you don't want any web page you visit to be able to make calls *from your desktop* to *any computer or server* into your office's intranet**

Comment: as I said above, this is a complete red herring. If your intranet is set up to take and process cgi requests, that page is just as likely to take advantage of those.  This is simply *not a real world concern!